# Enforce ONE to MANY relationship in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have 2 tables in my database.
Table 1 '**OrderItems**' and Table 2 '**Orders**'.
Each '**Order**' can have zero or more '**OrderItems**'.
I defined a FK constraint linking the primary keys: OrderId and OrderItemId with the DeleteRule set to 'Cascade'.
This ensures that all OrderItems will be deleted when I delete an Order.

What I need to avoid are empty Orders. I need to ensure that an Order has **AT LEAST** one **OrderItem**, otherwise it should be deleted automatically as soon as the last linked **OrderItem** is deleted. I could of course check for this in my app, but ideally the db can deal with this.

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 and Entity Framework as my ORM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a relationship is not enforceable using ordinary relational rules; after all, how would you add an order? If you can't add an order item without an order, but you can't have any orders without order items, you run into a chicken-or-the-egg scenario.

Your only real solution would be to create a delete trigger on the `OrderItem` table that deletes the corresponding order if it's the last item.

Comment: Does a delete trigger fire only on Delete's or will it fire on every change as @Dave Anderson suggests below?

Comment: @santiagoIT: You can define triggers that will fire for inserts, updates, and deletes.

Comment: How easily can delete trigger be made aware of data from the deleted records? For example, if I delete all `OrderItems` older than two years, will the trigger be able to identify the corresponding OrderIDs, or will it need to check all Orders for 0 children?

Comment: @djacobson: You may want to do some reading on triggers, but the short answer is that triggers provide two "pseudo-tables" (I'm not certain of the actual term, if there is one) called `INSERTED` and `DELETED`. These contain the rows that were inserted or deleted (respectively). Insert triggers only have values in `INSERTED`, delete triggers only have values in `DELETED`, and update triggers have values in both (the old row in `DELETED` and the new row in `INSERTED`)

Answer (score 1):

This bidirectional relationship may not be enforceable in the db schema. You probably will need to enforce this in your business logic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a constraint-based way to do this. You might have success with a trigger on deletes from the `OrderItem` table, that checks for "childless" `Order` records and deletes those... This may be a heavyweight "boil the ocean" approach, though, and you may be better off capturing this scenario in business logic, as @rcravens recommends.

Comment: Why would I be better off doing this in my business logic? Everytime an OrderItem is deleted I would also have to check if the Order has any other OrderItem's left. Am assuming that the delete trigger fires only on Delete.

Comment: @santiagoIT True, but the delete trigger may not be able to identify the OrderIDs of the deleted `OrderItem` records, and therefore has to scan every `Order` record to see if it has any remaining children (I could be wrong, but I know of no way for a trigger to get that kind of information from the triggering query). If you do this check in your business logic, you can hold onto the affected OrderIDs and only evaluate those `Orders` for deletion.

Comment: @santiagoIT Feel free to disregard my previous comment - @Adam Robinson has explained how triggers work in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an [UPDATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to check if you have any remaining order items and then archive the Order.

This will fire on every change to a row in the table so you should consider the logic and associated performance impact carefully.